# `NSDictionary` is not implicitly convertible to `[NSObject : AnyObject]`

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, multimedia

I have this function:

```
func audioRecordingSettings() -> NSDictionary {

        return [
            AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC as NSNumber,
            AVSampleRateKey : 16000.0 as NSNumber,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 1 as NSNumber,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Medium.rawValue as NSNumber
        ]
    }
```

Then I defined another:

```
func startRecordingAudio() {

    var error: NSError?

    let audioRecordingURL = self.audioRecordingPath()

    audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioRecordingURL, settings: audioRecordingSettings(), error: &error)
    //Here the error comes. 
 }
```

It asks me to add as `[NSObject: AnyObject]` after the `audioRecordingSetthings()`, I don't think that's the correct solution. 
Because when I called `startRecordingAudio()` in another `class`, it crashes with `Unexpectedly found nil`.

Comment: `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC as NSNumber` should be `NSNumber(unsignedInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)`, because basically a primitive cannot be casted as object directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add `audioRecordingSettings() as [NSObject : AnyObject]` in the `AVAudioRecorderDelegate`:

```
AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioRecordingURL, settings: audioRecordingSettings() as [NSObject : AnyObject], error: &error)
```

Additionally I would change your method to:

```
func audioRecordingSettings() -> [NSObject : AnyObject] {

    return [
        AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
        AVSampleRateKey : 16000.0,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 1,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Medium.rawValue
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `"AVAudioRecorder"` initializer which specifies:

```
init!(URL url: NSURL!, settings: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, error outError: NSErrorPointer)
```

So, you need to convert setting to  `[NSObject : AnyObject]`.